# Classifier.fit(X,y) error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying some machine learning algorithms.

I'm using sklearn tool for logistic regression script.

this is my script:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
#from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
X = np.array([[10000,80000,35],[7000,120000,57],[100,23000,22],[223,18000,26]])

y = np.array([1,1,0,0]).reshape((1, -1))
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X,y)
print(classifier.predict([5500,80000,25]))
```

The error that I got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logictic_regression2.py", line 11, in <module>
 classifier.fit(X,y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model
logistic.py", line 1142, in fit order="C")
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils
validation.py", line 515, in check_X_y
y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/util
/validation.py", line 551, in column_or_1d
raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LogisticRegression.fit()` method expects a one-dimensional array for the target vector `y`. The error you mentioned should be gone if you remove the `.reshape((1, -1))` that converts it into a 1x4 matrix (row vector).

Furthermore, the last line of your code

```
print(classifier.predict([5500,80000,25]))
```

raises a warning (at least in sklearn version 0.17.1) as for data a row per observation is expected. If you pass a two-dimensional numpy array (1x3 matrix) (`np.array([[5500,80000,25]]))`) everything works as expected.